# Why no Christmas or similar holiday hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

I was expecting some holiday hats like Christmas, Hanukkah, or New year but none of them were there this time.

Any reason for skipping Holiday hats?

Comment: those were always the trivial hats. This time they decided to make you work for all the hats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we decided to
change things up a bit this year:
no holiday hats

also, Hanukkah
ended on December 6th
so not relevant

but if you’re really
pining for holiday hats…
better luck next year

Comment: Does that mean Christmas and New year hats will be back next Winterbash?

Comment: @DebanjanB definitely maybe